# How to load values for different appsettings.json files from their respective properties files in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, properties-file, appsettings

I am working on a .NET Core project where I have an `appsettings.json` file for each environment (Dev, Prod). I want to load values for these appsettings files from the respective properties files (`application.dev.properties`, `application.prod.properties`).

I have tried using the Addpropertiesfile method like below to achieve this.

```
 using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
 using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.JSON;

 var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                      .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                      .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                      .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environment}.json");
```

How can I achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: What is properties file? I cannot see any result when searching "Addpropertiesfile" method at google. Where do you find this method?

Comment: I found this piece of code online @zolty13

Comment: Mayby you could share some link?

Comment: Then presumably the spot where you found it also tells you where to get that method presumably its also defined there (a ExtensionMethod)

Comment: Is there any other way of doing it @Ralf

Comment: I don't now what a properties file is here so can't really help. If you need different appsettings.json for different deployments then copy/rename the correct file as appsettings.json onto the target system. So solve the problem when deploying not at runtime.

Comment: @ravikiranreddy you're already doing what you want. .NET Core doesn't handle files named `appsettings.json` in *any* special way. All config sources are treated the same, with later sources overriding previous ones. If your files are JSON, you can load them as well just by appending an `AddJson` call. There are similar calls for INI and XML files.

Comment: @ravikiranreddy as for `Addpropertiesfile`, that's someone's custom extension method. We can't guess what that does or what files it works with. The name itself violates naming conventions so I bet this didn't come from a NuGet package, just some snippet. `I found this piece of code online` where? The rest of the article or Github repo should explain what this does.

Comment: Do you mean you want to get the value of the `appsettings.Development.json` ?

Answer (score 0):

In asp.net core we have the `appsettings.json`, `appsettings.{Environment}.json` like the structure:

[image]

Non-prefixed environment variables are environment variables other than those prefixed by ASPNETCORE_ or DOTNET_. **For example,** the ASP.NET Core web application templates set "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development" in `launchSettings.json`

[image]

```
"profiles": {
  "emp": {
    "commandName": "Project",
    "dotnetRunMessages": true,
    "launchBrowser": true,
    "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7271;http://localhost:5058",
    "environmentVariables": {
      "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
    }
  },
```

From [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-7.0),

> Using the default configuration, the
> EnvironmentVariablesConfigurationProvider loads configuration from
> environment variable key-value pairs after reading `appsettings.json`,
> `appsettings.{Environment}.json`, and user secrets. Therefore, key
> values read from the environment override values read from `appsettings.json`, `appsettings.{Environment}.json`, and user secrets.

To load values for different `appsettings.json` files, we can try to get the environment variables firstly, then loads configuration from environment variable key-value pairs after reading `appsettings.json`, `appsettings.{Environment}.json`  as the below code :

```
var pathToExe = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
var pathToContentRoot = Path.GetDirectoryName(pathToExe);
var environment= Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ;
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(pathToContentRoot)
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environment}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .Build();
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Please pay attention to the questions. This isn't the first answer that shows a misunderstanding of the question itself. The answer would be wrong even if the question was "How to I load environment-specific settings ?`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos   Thank you for your reminder. I guess the author's intention, and then give him a suitable solution in our core as a reference. If there are any questions in the future, I will continue to follow up.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to do this directly. This is done by default in .net core. See bullet point 4 below From [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#default-application-configuration-sources).

> ASP.NET Core web apps created with dotnet new or Visual Studio
> generate the following code:
>
> C#
>
> ```
> var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
> ```
>
> WebApplication.CreateBuilder initializes a new instance of the
> WebApplicationBuilder class with preconfigured defaults. The
> initialized WebApplicationBuilder (builder) provides default
> configuration for the app in the following order, from highest to
> lowest priority:

> 1. Command-line arguments using the Command-line configuration provider.
> 2. Non-prefixed environment variables using the Non-prefixed environment variables configuration provider.
> 3. User secrets when the app runs in the Development environment.
> 4. appsettings.{Environment}.json using the JSON configuration provider.
>    For example, appsettings.Production.json and
>    appsettings.Development.json.
> 5. appsettings.json using the JSON
>    configuration provider.
> 6. A fallback to the host configuration described
>    in the next section.

The c# code above will be placed in the Main function of the Program.cs file of a project and can automatically detect and use the correct appsettings.json file if it is named as shown.